# Ansible replace first occurrence on file

Tags: regular-expression, ansible

I am using Ansibles `replace` module, I want to replace only the first occurrence in the file.

I have example string:

```
example.string.in.my.text=test.@@sometext@@
```

I wish:

```
example.string.in.my.text=test.$$sometext@@
```

My Ansible play using the `replace` module:

```
- name: tasks replace
  replace:
     regexp: '(@@+?)'
     replace: '$$'
```

This tasks change for me all `@@`

```
example.string.in.my.text=test.$$sometext$$
```

How do I make it change only the first occurrence of `@@`?

Answer (score 1):

GMaster's answer will match the last occurrence in each line, the following version uses a non greedy match to find the first occurrence in a line, and the greedy match for the rest of the file to avoid matching any further occurrences on following lines:

```
- name: tasks replace
  replace:
    regexp: '^(.*?\.)@@([.\n]*)$'
    replace: '\1$$\2'
```

Answer based on the latest community version of https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html

Comment: If `ansible` uses PCRE,you should also be able to do `regexp: '^\G.*?\.\K@@'`, `replace: '$$'`. See the `pcrepattern` man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: tasks replace
  replace:
    regexp: '^(.*\.)@@(.*)$'
    replace: '\1$$\2'
```